# Encode string as octal utf-8 Python 3

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

Is there a good way to encode strings to utf-8, but in *octal* format instead of the default hexadecimal?

For example:

```
>>> "õ".encode("utf-8")
b'\xc3\xb5'
```

Here the output is hex, not octal. The output in octal would be: b'\303\265'

Python 3 automatically handles the decoding just fine:

```
>>> b"\xc3\xb5".decode("utf-8")
'õ'
>>> b'\303\265'.decode("utf-8")
'õ'
```

Is there a codec or option I'm missing? I'd like to avoid a lot of manual string manipulation.

update: I had misunderstood -- there is no difference between b"\xc3\xb5" and b'\303\265' at all, rather they are just 2 different ways to display the same underlying byte code. In fact:

```
>>> b"\xc3\xb5" == b'\303\265'
True
```

Comment: Note: you may be asking a very different question that you have written: Above the \xc3 is just a printable representation of the binary data. I think that you are asking about how to produce octal encoded escapes (so a pure ASCII text file), instead of how to encode to UTF-8

Comment: >>> b'\303\265' == b"\xc3\xb5"
True

Got it. The misunderstanding was that I believed that there were multiple possible encodings of UTF-8 chars (e.g., hex and octal), when actually this was just an artifact of how Python displays UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a class that overrides the representation of the string it wraps:

```
>>> class OctUTF8:
...   def __init__(self,s):
...     self.s = s.encode()
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return "b'" + ''.join(f'\\{n:03o}' for n in self.s) + "'"
...
>>> s='õ'
>>> OctUTF8(s)
b'\303\265'
```

This representation can be evaluated as a byte string and decoded back to the original:

```
>>> eval(repr(OctUTF8(s))).decode()
'õ'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use `ord()` to convert a character in a string 
to it's Unicode form, then, you can use `oct()`:

```
print(oct(ord("õ")))
```

Output:

```
0o365
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each byte in a bytes object to it's octal representation

```
[oct(b) for b in "õ".encode("utf-8")]
```

Gives

```
['0o303', '0o265']
```

You can manipulate the results to convert it to your desired output